# can i backport "pattern_replace" char filter into elasticsearch 0.19.9?

Tags: elasticsearch

our system is running elasticsearch 0.19.9. 
recentyly i'm going to add a new mapping on it. what i need is merge multiple whitespaces into a single whitespace.

i do some search ,and find pattern_replace is what i need, code are like

```
                "space_filter":{
                    "type":"pattern_replace",
                    "pattern":"\\s+",
                    "replacement":"\\s"
                }
```

but the bad news is "pattern_replace" is not introduced until 0.90.*. so is there possibily to backport this function into the version i'm using?

really i don't want to upgrade this system the newest version, guessing it's time consuming, as i'm also using es-head and bigdesk. the version match thing might kill me.

Comment: The answer is yes, of course it's possible. Unfortunately, anythings possible. The real question is will it be easy to do? That depends on whether you know Java and the ES internals, and I assume that if the answer to both of these questions is yes then you wouldn't be asking this question. You're also correct in assuming that upgrading from 0.19.x to 1.1.0 will break things. However, it might be less work than trying to back-port/write from scratch the functionality you require ES to do. Both the head and bigdesk plugins are supported in 1.1.0 but you'll probably have to upgrade them too.

Comment: exactly...i did a little code research, the copy work includes not only es but also lucene. better upgrade es's version directly.

Comment: Yeah. I upgraded from 0.19.x to 0.90.x quite some time ago now and i now keep it fully up to date on a regular basis. The upgrade from 0.19 can be a little hairy, but subsequent upgrades have been much much easier.